# Broken CSS Sprites

Tags: php, html, css

all.  I have some weird glitch going on with my CSS sprites displayed in the following code:

```
<footer>
    <div id="social">
        <a href="#" target="_blank" class="socialicons twitter">Twitter</a>
        <a href="#" target="_blank" class="socialicons linkedin">Linked In</a>
        <a href="#" target="_blank" class="socialicons facebook">Facebook</a>
        <a href="#" target="_blank" class="socialicons google">Google</a>
        <a href="#" target="_blank" class="socialicons flickr">Flickr</a>
        <span class="email">dan&#64;fifthgospelministries.com</span>
        <span class="phone">717-395-1234</span>
    </div>
</footer>
```

It works fine when the file is saved as an html file, but when I convert it to a php file the images break.

this can be viewed on idealbrandon.com/new/index.php (broken) and idealbrandon.com/new/index.html (working).

*edit* I forgot to include the css.
the relevant css is here:

```
footer{
    background: #323232;
    padding: 3em;
}

#social{
    width:60%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    width:250px;
    height:135px;
    padding-bottom:1em;
}

#social a{
    display:block;
}

.socialicons {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    float:left;
}

.twitter{  background: url('img/social.png') 0 0; }
.linkedin{ background: url('img/social.png') 200 0; }
.facebook{ background: url('img/social.png') 150 0; }
.google{   background: url('img/social.png') 100 0; }
.flickr{    background: url('img/social.png') 50 0; }

.twitter:hover{   background: url('img/social.png') 0 50; }
.linkedin:hover{  background: url('img/social.png') 200 50; }
.facebook:hover{  background: url('img/social.png') 150 50; }
.google:hover{    background: url('img/social.png') 100 50; }
.flickr:hover{     background: url('img/social.png') 50 50; }

.email{
    background-color:#8b8b8b;
}

.phone{
    background-color:#a6a6a6;
}

.email, .phone{
    font-weight: 400;
    color:#fff;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 3.2;
}

.email:hover, .phone:hover{
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#9c1e20;
}
```

Any thoughts here?

Comment: Next time, please _validate_ your code before asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS (style.css line 306):

```
.linkedin{ background: url('img/social.png') 200 0; }
```

should be:

```
.linkedin{ background: url('img/social.png') 200px 0; }
```

Units are generally required in CSS when non-zero.

Comment: Wow, I knew it was something silly.  I've just been staring at everything too long.  I will accept that answer as soon as it lets me (roughly 8 minutes).  Thanks for your help